# Замена bootstrap-vue для tailwind

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap, bootstrap-vue, tailwind

У меня есть большой проект, написанный на bootstrap vue. Это очень удобно, когда в пару строк кода можно сделать модальное окно с анимацией и со всем, что нужно.

Но я захотел переписать это на tailwind, так как он выглядит свежее и круче. И я нашел такую же библиотеку, как для bootstrap - [vue-tailwind](https://www.vue-tailwind.com/) Но это какая-то лажа в сравнении с bootstrap-vue. Либо я что-то не так понял)

Там нет никаких анимаций у модальных окон при появлении,
У некоторых элементов. например, t-alert нет стилей, у t-dialog стили есть, но там тоже нет анимаций.

Может вы знаете какие-нибудь библиотеки, которые здесь подойдут?
Или как решить проблему? Можно, конечно, самому всё написать, но у меня нет столько времени

Comment: Tailwind построен на совсем иных принципах, нежели Bootstrap - предполагая что разработчик будет сам составлять компоненты, а не бездумно пользоваться готовыми. Из похожих на Bootstrap библиотек, посмотри Bulma (это более молодой и свежий проект чем бутстрап, но принципы у него практически аналогичны BSным: есть готовые компоненты в базовой комплектации, плюс доп. компоненты сообщества).

Comment: Ну это просто Tailwind, а тут специальная библиотека с готовыми компонентами vue. В любом случае спасибо